# Enzyme - How can i access member variables of child component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I'm using enzyme to unit test react components. The previous version of enzyme i was using allowed me to access the child nodes and their member variables using node or nodes. Now the new version of enzyme that im using makes me use `getElement` function to access the child components. And `getElement` does not give me direct access to node or nodes (not suppported). How do i use `getElement` to set the member variable of the child component?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't forced to use `getElement`. Here's an example of how we unit test:

```
it('should pass entered password to password child textfield', () => {
    const inputPassword = 'gold please';
    const wrapper = enzyme.shallow((
      <Login
        emailAddress=""
        password={inputPassword}
        loggingIn={false}
        isValid={true}
        loginAutofilled={false}
        classes={{}}
        onEmailChanged={email => null}
        onPasswordChanged={password => null}
        onLoginAsGuest={() => null}
        onLogin={(email, password) => null}
        onResetPassword={() => null}
        onLoginAutofilled={() => null}
      />
    ));
    // There is an input element with an ID of 'login-form_password-field'
    const passwordField = wrapper.find('#login-form_password-field');
    expect(passwordField.props().value).toEqual(inputPassword);
  });
});
```